# Not seeing Welcome Screen when booting Ubuntu 20.04 from USB in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, usb

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 iso and created a USB with it.

I followed this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive

When I reboot my Ubuntu 16 and press F10, F12, or ESC, it just goes straight to my Ubuntu 16 and never goes to that Welcome screen

can anyone help?

EDIT: I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430

Comment: What sort of computer are you using? Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model? Some machines have different key combinations required to boot from USB.

Comment: I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430

Comment: If `f12` does not work, try `fn + f12`. https://www.digieffects.com/how-to-enter-bios-on-lenovo-laptop-t430/#4

Comment: By the way, you are probably using Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu 20 is [something](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/uc20) else. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I have ubuntu 16 right now but I want to install ubuntu 20.04

Comment: fn + f12 didn't work for me either

Comment: Please read the documentation for your computer. Accessing boot options is hardware specific. It it not controlled by any existing operating system.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't *burn* or write the ISO to your media correctly.  After you've downloaded an ISO (the ISO itself is just a file) you use special software to write to installation media in a form that is bootable; it doesn't sound like you did that.  Also do note; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a very different product to Ubuntu Core 16 (releases using the *year.month* format are different to those use the *year* format).

Comment: is it possible to enter bios with F1? look at the boot order.

Comment: to come in uefi settings you have to interrupt on uefi screen with enter then you have the choice to enter uefi setting search for enable f12 for bootmenue. .but I do not off-hand. know where it is stored.